# Compute Engine Linux Users and their relation to Service Accounts

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I was just wondering how the service account of the compute engine and the Linux users inside these compute engine play together.

If I log in a compute engine, I get a new Linux User with my Name. Does this user has the same permissions as my google account?

The root User on the compute engine uses the compute engine's Service Account, which is expected.

A newly created Linux user also uses the compute engine's Service Account.

Can you somehow configure a new Linux user to use a Google Account for Cloud API calls instead of the Compute engines Account?

Answer (score 1):

> I was just wondering how the service account of the compute engine and
>   the Linux users inside these compute engine play together.

There is no relationship between a Google Service Account and a Linux user.

> If I log in a compute engine, I get a new Linux User with my Name.
>   Does this user has the same permissions as my google account?

By Google Account, I am assuming you mean the one you use for Gmail, etc. There is no relationship between a Linux User (the username) and your Google Account.

When a Google Compute Engine VM instance is launched, credentials are created for the instance and stored in the metadata server. Each user can access these credentials. The credentials are the same for all Linux users on that instance. Permissions for these credentials is managed by scopes set in the Google Console OR via a service account assigned to the instance.

> The root User on the compute engine uses the compute engine's Service
>   Account, which is expected.

Incorrect assumption. The Linux users, which includes root, access credentials from the metadata server. This can either be scopes assigned to the instance or a service account. Note that credentials can have zero permissions.

> A newly created Linux user also uses the compute engine's Service
>   Account.

Same answer are the previous question.

> Can you somehow configure a new Linux user to use a Google Account for
>   Cloud API calls instead of the Compute engines Account?

There are three types of credentials. User Account Credentials (OAuth 2.0), Service Account Credentials, and API Keys.

To use User Account Credentials (for example, your Google Account), you would need to launch a web browser in the VM. By default, Google Compute Engine VMs do not have a desktop or GUI. Therefore no web browser. Therefore no User Account Credentials.

You can create a Service Account Json file and use these credentials on a per user or per application basis. You can also configure the Google SDK and Tools to use a specific service account (stored in a Json file).

The last option is API Keys. These are only used for certain APIs.